# Typescript call signature inference

Tags: typescript, flowtype

I am trying to convert the following Flow snippet to Typescript:

```
type Handler<Data> = (data: Data) => void
type Foo = { foo: string }
type AnyRequest = (path: '/foo', handler: Handler<Foo>) => void
type FooRequest = (path: string, handler: Handler<any>) => void

type RouterRequest = AnyRequest | FooRequest


function router(request: RouterRequest) {
   request('/foo', (data) => {
      // here data should be of type Foo
   })

   request('/bar', (data) => {
      // here data should be of type any  
   })  
}
```

Here flow can properly infer that the type of `data` by using the `path` parameter. See [running snippet](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1ACQIYB2AJtFgE4A8AIvivgHygC8oAFMXfgFyi30BKFkwBusAJbFUmHADFYsFqADeoSAt4BnFOXGEA5qAC+07KACChNACUsARwCuWbUrYY6AC14ByYOtjeADSgHkSkFLwEJGRU8rAMQsyiElLoZnG2js4oru4oXqDaugbBodEReGExlERoCcKgYpLIaTjWsA4oFJlOLqyWNva9OQA+oBlD2YigMzPIkA6EAMYo4rCEoOQdXeRs5JPavO2d3QcoQsrTM-tZ2my+-kHsnIINl7MAkBxcAHT+Wjo9PohLMrsYBFcwTdhvdgAAjfDkJ7fV5JFRgr4vfB-DSFQEGEFzWZGEGIExAA)

The same code in Typescript fail to infer the type of `data`
Pasting this code int the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) give me this error

> Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'RouterRequest' has no compatible call signatures.

Is there any way to achieve something similar in Typescript?

Comment: Elaborate `The same code in Typescript fail` please

Comment: I mean Typescript fail to infer the type of data. The actual error in the playground is: "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'RouterRequest' has no compatible call signatures."

Comment: Hmmm. Not sure how it is supposed to work. The type of `request` can not be inferred in my opinion, since it is not known upfront whether `AnyRequest` or `FooRequest` is passed in. I wish I understood TS type inference better.

Comment: In other words, I think, in TypeScript you need to explicitly check the type of the argument provided and branch on that

Comment: Yes, or do what @jcalz suggests!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `RouterRequest` type that allows full contextual typing...

```
type RouterRequest = {
  (path: "/foo", handler: Handler<Foo>): void;
  (path: string, handler: Handler<any>): void;
}
```

Full example:

```
type Handler<Data> = (data: Data) => void;
type Foo = { foo: string }

type RouterRequest = {
  (path: "/foo", handler: Handler<Foo>): void;
  (path: string, handler: Handler<any>): void;
}

function router(request: RouterRequest) {
    request('/foo', (data) => {
        // data is of type Foo
    })

    request('/bar', (data) => {
        // data is of type any  
    })  
}
```

Comment: Who downvoted this correct answer? I came here to write this and Fenton beat me by seconds

Comment: thanks so much that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you mean `RouterRequest` to be the *intersection* of `AnyRequest` and `FooRequest`, not their *union*.  Like so:

```
type RouterRequest = AnyRequest & FooRequest;
```

The type `AnyRequest | FooRequest` refers to something where you don't know if it is an `AnyRequest` or a `FooRequest`.  TypeScript is more or less warning you that it doesn't know which one it is so it won't let you call it at all (although maybe it [should](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14107#issuecomment-312070139) let you call it with an intersection of the parameters, but I digress.)

But you expect to be able to call it with either set of parameters.  That's more like an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) (or an intersection of function types) than a union.

If you change the above line, it should work for you, assuming that the `RouterRequest` really can be called in both ways.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Nice answer @jcalz

Comment: Yes that works too, thks! How `&` is different from typing 
type RouterRequest = {
  (path: "/foo", handler: Handler<Foo>): void;
  (path: string, handler: Handler<any>): void;
}

Comment: It's essentially the same thing... an intersection of two function types behaves as an overload (which means that intersections aren't strictly commutative: `A & B` can behave differently from `B & A`).

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
type RouterRequest = {
    (path: '/foo', handler: Handler<Foo>) :void  
    (path: string, handler: Handler<any>):void;
}
```